# Logging to a file on Android

Tags: android, logging

Is there any way of retrieving log messages from an Android handset.

I'm building an application which uses the GPS of my HTC Hero. I can run and debug the application from eclipse but this isn't a good use case of GPS, sat at my desk.

When I fire the app up when I am walking around, I get an intermittent exception. Is there anyway I can output these exceptions to a text file on the SD card or output calls to `Log.x("")` to a text file so that I can see what the exception is.

Thanks

**EDIT : Solution**

Here is the code I finally went with...

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

    PrintWriter pw;
    try {
        pw = new PrintWriter(
                new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/rt.log", true));
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

I had to wrap the line

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/rt.log", true));
```

in a try/catch as Eclipse would not let me compile the app. It kept saying

> ```
> Unhandled exception type IOException
>
> 1 quick fix
>     Sorround with try/catch
> ```

So I did and it all works which is fine by me but it does make me wonder what Eclipse was on about...

Comment: Nice if you have one thread writing but what happens to this solution if you have 5 threads writing to the same file, not a good solution then.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) to catch the Exceptions.

Writing to SD Card is as simple as retrieving the directory for the card using [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) and creating a file there.

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),filename);
```

You will need to give you app the correct permission to write to the SD Card by adding this to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Cheers Dave, I'll give it a pop

Answer (score 6):

Log4j or slf4j can also be used as logging frameworks in Android together with logcat. See the project [android-logging-log4j](http://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/). Configuring logging to a (rotating) file(s) is very easy.

```
 static {
    final LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();

    logConfigurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "myapp.log");
    logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    // Set log level of a specific logger
    logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
    logConfigurator.configure();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could take a look at microlog4android. They have a solution ready to log to a file.

https://github.com/johanlkarlsson/microlog4android

Answer (score 4):

I tried both options above (microlog4android & android-logging-log4j) and they were a struggle to try to get working.  Once they compiled fine then I would get Runtime java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

So then I stumbled on [logback-android](http://tony19.github.com/logback-android/)
... also found here http://logback.qos.ch/

It has much better instructions and I got it working in a couple hours.

This appears to be the best logging solution for Android.

Answer (score 4):

Use [slf4-android](https://github.com/bright/slf4android) lib created by [BrightInventions](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/). It's simple implementation of [slf4j api](http://www.slf4j.org/) using android java.util.logging.*.

Features:

- logging to file out of the box
- logging to any other destination by `LoggerConfiguration.configuration().addHandlerToLogger`
- shake your device to send logs with screenshot via email
- really small, it tooks only ~55kB

slf4android is maintained mainly by [@miensol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155213/miensol).

Read more about slf4android on our blog:

- [Introducing slf4android](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/introducing-slf4android/)
- [Integrate slf4android with Crashlytics](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/integrate-slf4j-with-crashlytics/)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Greg B solution and @JPM question in the comment, I made this static method in a seperate class and each time you instanciate a new thread, call it.

package com.stackoverflow.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import android.os.Environment;

public class UnhandledExceptionHandler {

    public static void setUndhandledException(Thread thread) {
        if (thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler() == null) {
            Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
                    new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread,
                                Throwable ex) {

                            PrintWriter pw;
                            try {
                                pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(Environment
                                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + "/rt-networkandgps"
                                        + "/gpx/"
                                        + thread.getId() + ".log", true));
                                ex.printStackTrace(pw);
                                pw.flush();
                                pw.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

}
```

Call it from anythread like this,

```
            UnhandledExceptionHandler.setUndhandledException(Thread.currentThread());
```