# How long do Android log entries stay in memory

Tags: android, logging, buffer

I'm developing a location monitoring application for Android. One of my requirements is for it to be able to run for 7 continuous hours. To test that requirement I'm going to use the Android logging system to log the percentage of battery life left every 5 minutes (or possibly more). I might do this for an hour and then do some maths and work out if the application could run for 7 hours.

I read that the log entries are stored in a buffer. How often is this buffer flushed? Is there a better way for me to test my application?

I'm still doing some research on different approaches to take but unfortunately most testing guides assume that your device is connected to a PC.

Source : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: As a side note, your "7 continuous hours" requirement is worryingly vague. Is it 7hrs on a particular device? Is the battery new? What's the air temperature going to be? (OK, that's probably overkill but if it's for an arctic research team then it could be important!)

Comment: Its a University assignment so I'm not overly worried about being 100% exact. I'm going to test it on a couple of devices that run Android.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it depends how much logging you (and other apps, and the system) are doing. Logcat uses a fixed-*size* buffer, rather than one with a maximum-age.

You can do `adb logcat -g` to see the size of the buffer on your device, as it varies.

Comment: Is there any way to ensure that log entries that my application writes are kept?

Comment: Sure. Write them to a text file instead.

Comment: As Geobits said, your best bet is to log to a file instead of logcat. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116260/logging-to-a-file-on-android