# How to create a simple looping service that prints to the logs in the background for android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simple service that prints to the logs every few seconds, even when the app is back grounded, and although I've researched this, I'm still bemused as to how I could do it. I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me a bit of code that I could use to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceClass.java   (IntentService starts on a new thread, we do not need to create a new thread in it.)

```
  public class IntentServiceDemo extends IntentService {
          int currentState=0;

      public IntentServiceDemo() {
        super("IntentServiceDemoWorker");  // super the name of worker thread, it is necessary.
    }
    @Override
     protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                       ++currentState:
                    Log.d("vabhi", "currentState : " + currentState);
                }  // End of while
    }
}
```

Mainifest (inside application tag)

```
<service android:name=".IntentServiceDemo" android:exported="false"></service>
```

inside MainActivity.java

```
public void startIntentService(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,IntentServiceDemo.class);
    startService(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**LOGGING**

[Android Writing Logs to text File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file)

[Logging to a file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116260/logging-to-a-file-on-android)

**BACKGROUND**

[How to run an android app in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029040/how-to-run-an-android-app-in-background)